# Inexpensive entry-level digitizer (a.k.a. graphics tablet) for Photoshop

Tags: graphics-tablet

I'm sick of trying to use my mouse to do Photoshop drawing.  I know the standard is to to use a digitizer (a.k.a., pen tablet), but I don't want to sink hundreds of dollars into one when I really just need something more ergonomic and responsive than a mouse for some details.

Are there any obvious entry-level digitizers, or is it not worth it until I'm ready to pay up for the pro-grade digitizers?

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for something like a Wacom tablet?

Comment: Yes.  Is there a different term for that category of input hardware?

Comment: I just wasn't familiar with that term, wanted to make sure it was what I thought it was. It does look like that's the official term.

Comment: I've always seen them referred to as drawing tablets, though Wikipedia redirects that term to [graphics tablet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet). Perhaps we should take a page out of their book? I've never seen them referred to as digitizers before this question (though wiki does recognize that as an alternative name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently got a [Wacom Intuos Pen Small](https://store.wacom.com/us/en/product/CTL480/), and I love it.

It does everything I need it to do and it skips out on all the extra buttons and features that probably aren't needed anyway.

The price tag comes in at about $80.

The size of the area that you can draw in is about 6"x4" inches. The actual size is about 8"x7" It might seem a bit small, but it's really plenty.

It comes with 1024 levels of presure sensitivity. I know some of the more expensive models have more, but this is enough for my purposes.

It also has four buttons at the top for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the Windows Key. Each of which can be customized.

Comment: Weird: the Pen & Touch Small (CTH-480) I bought a year ago for $80 *did* have an eraser, although I normally just toggle to erase mode rather than flipping it over to use the pen's eraser.

Comment: Huh, maybe they changed something. On the site it says that it doesn't have one. I use Krita for drawing so if it does have one, it doesn't work there anyway. I'll get rid of that bit in case I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree that the current Intuos Pen Smalls don't appear to have them (per their online specs).  I was just noting the odd feature change.

Answer (score 1):

No question: Get a Wacom Intuous.  Available for under $100, this will provide all the key features serious graphic artists and photographers use in Photoshop, Illustrator, and the like: high resolution pressure sensitivity, touch sensitivity.  It has a large enough surface that you might never feel the need to upgrade.

And you may even find it to be a useful replacement for your mouse in more traditional applications.